# rxjava: emitting one result of all observables instead of multiple

Tags: java, rx-java

The situation is that my getData() method is called with a parameter of list of Strings. For each of the strings I need to perform some action in getDataPerItem(). At the end the results of each calls to getDataPerItem() should be merged into one big List (that keeps the order of results) and getData() should emit all result in a *single list*. With the current approach it will emit one List for each identifier separately. How to merge all the results into one?

```
public Observable<List<Model>> getData(List<String> identifiers) {
    return Observable.from(identifiers).flatMap { identifier -> getDataPerItem(identifier) };
}

public Observable<List<Model>> getDataPerItem(String identifier) {
    return xxx;
}
```

Comment: Have a look at `reduce`: Start with an empty list and `addAll` the items from each of the partial responses. But feel free to update your question if you're stuck!

Comment: Also, I think `getDataPerItem` should really just do one request. It is the Rx chain in `getData` that needs some work: `Observable.from(identifiers).concatMap { identifier -> getDataPerItem(identifier) }.reduce(...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to accomplish this:

One solution is to use `concatMapIterable` and then collect everything in a list:

```
public Single<List<Model>> getData(List<String> identifiers) {
    return Observable
        .from(identifiers)
        .concatMap(identifier -> getDataPerItem(identifier))
        .concatMapIterable(it -> it)
        .toList();
}
```

Another solution is to `reduce` into an `ArrayList`:

```
public Single<List<Model>> getData(List<String> identifiers) {
    return Observable
        .from(identifiers)
        .concatMap(identifier -> getDataPerItem(identifier))
        .reduce(new ArrayList<Model>(), (list, next) -> list.addAll(next));
}
```

Note that the return type is `Single` because it only emits one item: the list containing everything.